# Fluent binding unable to cast to model with EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, fluent

I'm trying to setup a fairly complicated data model, and as far as the sql side of things goes its pretty straight forward, however I'm running into an odd problem in my fluent configuration in my database context.

what I have is 3 tables, 2 of which share a common table called tasks which is as follows:

```
[PK][Id]
[UserId]
[TaskType]
[CreatedDate]
[CompletedDate]
```

The other three tables look as follows:

Print:

```
[PK][Id]
[TaskId]
[TaskItemId]
[Scnumber]
[Address]
[City]
[Province]
[PostalCode]
[Country]
```

Cancel:

```
[PK][Id]
[TaskId]
[TaskItemId]
[Scnumber]
```

If I were to do everything in SQL there wouldn't be any issues, but in EntityFramework my db context is having an issue when I try to add a task with print items associated with it.

```
public partial class Tasks
{
   public Tasks()
   {
      Items = new HashSet<ITaskItem>();
   }

   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public byte TaskType { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }

   public ICollection<ITaskItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public interface ITaskItem { }

public partial class Cancelations : ITaskItem
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public long TaskId { get; set; }
   public string TaskItemId { get; set; }
   public long Scnumber { get; set; }

   public Tasks Task { get; set; }
}

public partial class Print : ITaskItem
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public long TaskId { get; set; }
   public string TaskItemId { get; set; }
   public long Scnumber { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string Province { get; set; }
   public string PostalCode { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; }

   public Tasks Task { get; set; }
}
```

So here in my db context, when I'm building out Cancellation and Print, when I specify the relationship I'm explicitly casting to the correct type, but ti doesn't seem to work and instead casts to the wrong type. In the case when I try to create a task with print items, I get a casting error, but when I add cancellation items there's no problems. I can't really figure out why this is happening.

```
public partial class DemoDbContext : DbContext
{
   public virtual DbSet<Cancelations> Cancelations { get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<Print> Print { get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
      if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
      {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"connection string here");
      }
   }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {

      modelBuilder.Entity<Print>(entity =>
      {
            entity.ToTable("Print", "cdi");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.TaskItemId)
               .HasName("UQ_Print_TaskItemId")
               .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Address).HasMaxLength(150);

            entity.Property(e => e.City).HasMaxLength(75);

            entity.Property(e => e.Country).HasColumnType("char(2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.PostalCode).HasMaxLength(15);

            entity.Property(e => e.ProcessedDate)
               .HasColumnType("datetime")
               .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Province).HasMaxLength(5);

            entity.Property(e => e.TaskItemId)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasColumnType("nchar(39)")
               .HasDefaultValueSql("(concat('P-',newid()))");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Task)
               .WithMany(p => ((ICollection<Print>)p.Items))
               .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskId)
               .HasConstraintName("FK_Print_Tasks");
      });

      modelBuilder.Entity<Cancelations>(entity =>
      {
            entity.ToTable("Cancelations", "cdi");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.TaskItemId)
               .HasName("UQ_Cancelations_TaskItemId")
               .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.ProcessedDate)
               .HasColumnType("datetime")
               .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.TaskItemId)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasColumnType("nchar(39)")
               .HasDefaultValueSql("(concat('C-',newid()))");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Task)
               .WithMany(p => ((ICollection<Cancelations>)p.Items))
               .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskId)
               .HasConstraintName("FK_Cancelations_Tasks");
      });

      modelBuilder.Entity<Tasks>(entity =>
      {
            entity.ToTable("Tasks", "cdi");

            entity.Property(e => e.CompletedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasMaxLength(36);
      });
   }
}
```

When I attempt to do the following I get this error:

var context = new DemoDbContext();

```
var task = new Tasks
{
   CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
};

var items = new List<ITaskItem>
{
   new Print
   {
   Scnumber = 0000000001,
   Address = "123 Demo St",
   City = "Toronto",
   Province = "ON",
   PostalCode = "H0H0H0",
   Country = "CA",
   ProcessedDate = DateTime.Now

   },
   new Print
   {
   Scnumber = 0000000001,
   Address = "123 Demo St",
   City = "Toronto",
   Province = "ON",
   PostalCode = "H0H0H0",
   Country = "CA",
   ProcessedDate = DateTime.Now

   },
};

task.Items = items; //cancellations;
task.UserId = "moo cow";
task.TaskType = 1;

try
{
      context.Tasks.Add(task);
      context.SaveChanges();
} catch(Exception ex)
{
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

`Unable to cast object of type 'temp.Models.Print' to type 'temp.Models.Cancelations'.`

Comment: When do you get the error and what is the exact error?

Comment: shit totally for forgot the most important part

Comment: You cannot do this: `ICollection<ITaskItem>` and then start adding every thing to it that implements the `ITaskItem` interface. What is the point of that interface? Please read about *Covariance, and Contravariance in C#* and make sure you understand that clearly before you attempt to do what you are trying to do. Simply stated, you cannot do that.

Comment: I'm amazed it tolerates `ICollection<T>`...

Comment: @Marqueone You will have to declare two separate navigational properties on the `Task` for `Print` and `Cancelations`. EF can't infer that this interfaces is a db table, since it is not mappable (you didn't declare it in fluent and it has no annotations). IMO you won't be able to trick it even using fluent, because EF needs concrete classes as properties.

Comment: Also, think logically. even if this error didn't happen, which table should EF query when you do `.Include(task => task.Items)`?